# Unique Indexes for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out what I'm missing for my syntax errors to get corrected so I can apply a unique index to a field in my table called vehicleDrive.

```
ALTER TABLE `vehicleDrive` ADD UNIQUE `name`;
```

I'm receiving this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: User `CREATE INDEX`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `vehicleDrive` ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

**[SQL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)**

Answer (score 1):

How about doing:

```
create unique index idx_vehicleDrive_name on vehicleDrive(name);
```

This also gives the index a name.

For your syntax, you need parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE `vehicleDrive` ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some brackets around the column name:

```
ALTER TABLE vehicleDrive ADD UNIQUE (name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax:

```
alter table <table_name> 
  add unique index <index_name> (<column_name> (8000))
```

So try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE vehicleDrive ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_unique_name (name)
```